# Traducir un párrrafo en Laravel con JSON

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo la traducción de un sitio con la opción de JSON, y para oraciones pequeñas me funciona bien, pero cuando intento hacerlo con un párrafo no hace la traducción. Uso clave : valor

```
"The new city": "La nueva ciudad" // Funciona
```

Pero con Párrafos no:

```
"Para nosotros nuestros clientes son nuestra prioridad y le damos trato personalizado, cada caso es distinto y requiere de estrategias especiales. Estamos para servirle y guiarle en todo su proceso.": "For us, our clients are our priority and we give them personalized treatment, each case is different and requires special strategies. We are here to serve you and guide you in your process."
```

Párrafo más grande

```
"Sabemos lo abrumador que puede ser llenar correctamente los formularios de Inmigración, cualquier error puede causar que la aplicación se retrase o sea rechazada. Nosotros lo podemos ayudar desde el llenado de los formularios, guiarlo en los documentos y evidencias que deben acompañar a la aplicación que será sometida a Inmigración, así como darle seguimiento a su caso y responder a cualquier inquietud que surja durante su proceso y hasta obtener una respuesta por parte de USCIS. No somos abogados en Inmigración pero tenemos vasta experiencia en esta área para darle el apoyo que usted necesita. Para nosotros nuestros clientes son nuestra prioridad y le damos trato personalizado, cada caso es distinto y requiere de estrategias especiales. Estamos para servirle y guiarle en su proceso migratorio.": "We know how overwhelming it can be to fill out Immigration forms correctly, any mistake can cause the application to be delayed or rejected. We can help you from filling out the forms, guiding you in the documents and evidence that must accompany the application that will be submitted to Immigration, as well as following up on your case and answering any concerns that arise during its process and even obtaining a response from USCIS. We are not immigration attorneys but we have vast experience in this area to give you the support you need. For us, our clients are our priority and we give them personalized treatment, each case is different and requires special strategies. We are here to serve and guide you through your immigration process.",
```

Comment: Porque en Laravel se usa un archivo JSON para hacer la traducción, se escribe cada palabra, oración o párrafo en un JSON con su respectivo Clave:Valor, ejemplo: "Acerca de nosotros":"About us", pero con los párrafos no me funciona.

Comment: Lo escribí en la pregunta, ve el ejemplo de: "The new city": "La nueva ciudad"

Comment: No, esas comillas se crearon conel texto de stackoverflow para poner el código, no lo eliminó... En mi texto real notengo comillas dentro del texto, igual no funciona. Puse aquí un lorem ipsum

Comment: Bueno, agrega el json real, si no va a ser difícil ver que pasa... O usa algún validador de json, hay varios en línea, por ej https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ya lo agregué a la pregunta

Comment: Lo recibo con {{ __($content->title_01) }} y {!! __(nl2br($content->content_01)) !!} para los párrafos, incluso lo intenté con la primera para párrafos y nada, todas las demás me funcionan bien

Comment: Probé esto `{{__('Para nosotros nuestros clientes son nuestra prioridad y le damos trato personalizado, cada caso es distinto y requiere de estrategias especiales. Estamos para servirle y guiarle en todo su proceso.')}}` y esto `@lang("Para nosotros nuestros clientes son nuestra prioridad y le damos trato personalizado, cada caso es distinto y requiere de estrategias especiales. Estamos para servirle y guiarle en todo su proceso.")` en una vista y funcionan perfectamente.

Comment: Sí, ese ya me funcionó, nose que había pasado. Pero los de textos más largos aún no funcionan.Lo agrego a la pregunta.

Comment: Ya sé que pasa... Dejé esto para el final del proyecto. El tema está en que yo obtengo ese párrafo desde la base de datos por medio de una variable, le hago una salto de línea al párrafo y utilizo el siguiente método para darle formato en la vista {!! __(nl2br($content->content_01)) !!}, ahora no sé como resolverlo, coloqué \n en el JSON para identificar el salto de línea pero no funciona, también tengo entendido que el método convierte \n en <br/>. Sabrás como resolverlo? si coloco todo el párrafo continuo sin salto de línea funciona bien la traducción.